# Best way to store text data in an android app?

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, apk

I've made an Android application which contains most used German words and sentences. The application contains a CSV file which stores all the data.

Currently it is working as expected but I want to ask if there is a better way to store such data directly in the app?

I'm also thinking about the ability to update the data via internet like adding new words and sentences.

Thanks!
Miretz

Comment: what kind of app is it? If you just need to store information, you could use either string xml file or the database.

Comment: Yes, I just store the information in the app, the app just reads and searches in the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to modify the content (update, remove etc.) I would suggest using [SQLite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) which has a pretty nice built-in integration with the Android platform.

Comment: Even if you don't need to modify it, you'll only need to read from your CSV file once, to load the database, and then you'll get faster access from the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types SQLDatabaseLite and SharedPreference. Major difference between both is that one is organized and the other not so.

If you need a quick use of a storage facility within your app for example changing text sizes between activity SharedPrefference works best for you.

If you have a complex database system where you need more than one data to be saved for a particular event SQLDatabaseLite is for you example of this is spreadsheet of data for customers; Name, Phone Number, etc.